# jQuery .keydown(), .keyup() ignoring "I", "B"

Tags: jquery, events, contenteditable, jquery-events

I've got a bit of code here, which works okay in TextMate's web preview, but Safari is doing something that I'm not sure how to get around...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('*[contentEditable="true"]').focusin(function(){
    var _self = this;
    var isCtrl = false;
    // Bind events.
    $(window).keyup( function(e) {
      if(e.which==17 || e.which == 91) isCtrl=false;
    });
    $(window).keydown( function(e){
      if(e.which==17 || e.which == 91) isCtrl=true;
      if(isCtrl) {
        console.log(e.which);
        switch(e.which) {
          case 66:  doCommand('bold');
                    break;
          case 67:  doCommand('cut');    
                    break;
          case 73:  doCommand('italic'); 
                    break;
          case 86:  doCommand('paste');  
                    break;
          default:  break;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }).focusout(function(){
    $(window).unbind();
  });
});
```

When <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> is pressed, we should get an event to make the text in the `contentEditable` area italic. The problem is, while other standard ASCII/Alpha character will fire, B and I do not. Now, if I `preventDefault()`, still nothing.

I need a fresh pair of eyes on this. Can anyone else see a way around this that won't prevent me from typing still?

**Edit**
To clarify, yes this works fine with other text input elements (`<textarea>`, `<input>`, etc.). It's specifically related to `contentEditable`.

Also, `doCommand` is included here:

```
doCommand = function(cmd) {
  document.execCommand(cmd, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no need to detect modifier keys separately. You can find out from the `keyup` or `keydown` event whether the <kbd>cmd</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys were held down using the event's `ctrlKey` and `metaKey` properties.

Second, in `contenteditable` elements, keyboard shortcuts for bold and italic commands are already built in by the browser.

It's certainly possible to intercept the keypresses you want. See http://jsfiddle.net/Hq43A/

Comment: Good to know. Still doesn't answer my question - How can I intercept "b" or "i"?

Comment: @stslavik: There's nothing else obviously wrong with your code, and it's certainly possible to intercept ctrl-b and ctrl-i.

Comment: @stslavik: I've added a jsFiddle example to my answer.

Comment: Excellent. I was putting the preventDefault in a completely wrong place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've got something wrong in your doCommand function.

Look [here](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/83824/1) and try it. You'll see it alerts "italic" on CTRL + I.

Try to put some alerts into your function(s), you'll see it will help you a lot when debugging.

Comment: Good, but you've got an important change – This isn't on a `<textarea>`. It's something about the combination of `contentEditable` and the keydown event. When `isCtrl == true` it will register, for instance, "e" but not "i" or "b".

Comment: @stslavik: it is probably that problem. Try to change it to data-contenteditable and try again

Comment: change all "contentEditable" occurences to "data-contenteditable", because if i know correctly, contentEditable is not valid attr

Comment: contentEditable is accessible through jQuery as an (html5) attribute name. data-contenteditable gives no result.